# Linq error in the select statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a function which returns the result of a LINQ statement. Please check piece of code which is throwing an error.

```
            var result = devices
                .Select(d =>
                        new
                        {
                            deviceName = d.SystemDeviceName,
                            deviceType = d.SystemDeviceTypeName,
                            dvrVersion = d.DVRVersion,
                            numCameras = d.NumCameras,
                            lastPing = d.LastPingDate!=null? d.LastPingDate:null,
                            audioType = d.AudioTypeName ?? "(None)",
                            videoProvider = d.Provider,
                            ipAddress = d.IPAddress,
                            vpnIpAddress = d.VPNIPAddress,
                            internalUseIpAddress = d.InternalUseIPAddress,
                            viewLiveLink = "<a onclick='openViewer(" + d.SystemDeviceID + ", true)'>"
                                    + (ShowIcon ? "<img src='images/video-live.png'>" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowIcon && ShowText ? "&nbsp;" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowText ? "View Live" : String.Empty)
                                    + "</a>",
                            viewSearchLink = "<a onclick='openViewer(" + d.SystemDeviceID + ", false)'>"
                                    + (ShowIcon ? "<img src='images/video-recorded.png'>" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowIcon && ShowText ? "&nbsp;" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowText ? "View Recorded" : String.Empty)
                                    + "</a>",
                        })
                .ToArray();

            response.Object = result;
            return response;
```

I am getting error from the `var result = devices.select` statement.

Error is :

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ
>   to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I tried to identify which assignment is throwing the error. The following lines are causing the error,

```
viewLiveLink = "<a onclick='openViewer(" + d.SystemDeviceID + ", true)'>"
                                + (ShowIcon ? "<img src='images/video-live.png'>" : String.Empty)
                                + (ShowIcon && ShowText ? "&nbsp;" : String.Empty)
                                + (ShowText ? "View Live" : String.Empty)
                                + "</a>",
                        viewSearchLink = "<a onclick='openViewer(" + d.SystemDeviceID + ", false)'>"
                                + (ShowIcon ? "<img src='images/video-recorded.png'>" : String.Empty)
                                + (ShowIcon && ShowText ? "&nbsp;" : String.Empty)
                                + (ShowText ? "View Recorded" : String.Empty)
                                + "</a>",
```

The class defenition for the devices is,

```
public partial class VideoDevice
{
    public VideoDevice()
    {
        this.ImageApeSubscriptions = new HashSet<ImageApeSubscription>();
    }

    public int VideoDeviceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SiteId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
    public int SystemDeviceID { get; set; }
    public int CompanySystemID { get; set; }
    public string SystemDeviceName { get; set; }
    public string SystemDeviceTypeName { get; set; }
    public int NumCameras { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string DVRVersion { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string VPNIPAddress { get; set; }
    public string InternalUseIPAddress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PrimaryCameraID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastPingDate { get; set; }
    public string AudioTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ViewerClassName { get; set; }
    public string ViewerName { get; set; }
    public string OverrideIP { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ImageApeSubscription> ImageApeSubscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me to clear the bug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: datatype conversation problem in your code. please check your datatype.

Comment: Which Entity Framework version you use? Try to explicitly convert `d.SystemDeviceID` to string (`d.SystemDeviceID.ToString()`).

Comment: `I am getting error from the var result = devices.select statement.` As a general LINQ rule, if you get a runtime error take bits out of the LINQ query line by line. When the error stops, the bit you just removed was the problematic one.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and separate data and UI concerns. It's not good to let a database query produce html. For each tiny UI change you have to change a query (tests etc.). Get the data first, then do the UI stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework cant convert all linq queries to sql but you can pre query for do that.

```
var result = devices
.ToArray()//<< solution
.Select(d => new{
  ..
})
.ToArray();
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try convert `SystemDeviceID` to string before you put this value as part of string

```
 viewLiveLink = "<a onclick='openViewer(" + d.SystemDeviceID.ToString() + ", true)'>"
                                    + (ShowIcon ? "<img src='images/video-live.png'>" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowIcon && ShowText ? "&nbsp;" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowText ? "View Live" : String.Empty)
                                    + "</a>",
                            viewSearchLink = "<a onclick='openViewer(" + d.SystemDeviceID.ToString() + ", false)'>"
                                    + (ShowIcon ? "<img src='images/video-recorded.png'>" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowIcon && ShowText ? "&nbsp;" : String.Empty)
                                    + (ShowText ? "View Recorded" : String.Empty)
                                    + "</a>",
```

Comment: This one I tried before posting this question. But it was giving me error. Onething I just noticed is that when I select the Id in a select and then frame the HTML in another select, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you using EF6 or EF Core ?

Secondly, we have very little information as to what `devices` is or could be, if you could manage to supply any more information, that would be great.

Thirdly, try to isolate the erroneous instruction so it is not bloated by unnecessary/un-relevant pieces of code, your post could probably be refactored to contain the core information related to your problem, you might also solve it 'rubber ducky' style while doing so.

Comment: My EF version is 4.0.0.0